# MongoTemplate aggregate - group by date

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

I'm trying to create an aggregate query using mongotemplate where there's a grouping by date (i.e 2016-03-01) instead of datetime (i.e 2016-03-01 16:40:12). 
The `dateToString` operation exists in the mongodb documentation it can be used to extract the date from the datetime using formatting:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/
but I get get it to work with mongotemplate - I get a NullPointerException.
(my db version is 3.2)

```
List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperations = new ArrayList<AggregationOperation>();

aggregationOperations.add(
          Aggregation.project("blabla", ...).
          andExpression("dateToString('%Y-%m-%d',timeCreated).as("date"));

aggregationOperations.add(Aggregation.group("date").sum("blabla").as("blabla"));

AggregationResults<?> aggregationResults = this.mongoTemplate.aggregate(
                        Aggregation.newAggregation(aggregationOperations),
                                    collectionName,
                                    resultClass);
```

When I use `dayOfMonth(timeCreated)` to extract the day, there's no exception, but I couldn't find and example of how to make this work with `dateToString`. I tried without '' for the date format, and it also didn't work...

This is the exception I  get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:226)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:194)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:255)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:194)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:255)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:194)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:255)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putIterable(BasicBSONEncoder.java:324)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:263)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:194)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:136)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:36)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.writeQuery(OutMessage.java:211)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.query(OutMessage.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:81)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:320)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:299)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:374)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$2.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:357)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$2.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:355)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:442)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeCommand(MongoTemplate.java:355)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1497)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1432)
```

**EDIT:**

Eventually we decided here on a different solution than what was suggested below, I'm writing it here in case anyone else finds it useful:

In addition to the "timeCreated" field which holds the datetime, we saved another field in the document: "date", that holds just the date (as long).

For example if "timeCreated" = "2015-12-24 16:36:06.657+02:00", then date is "2015-12-24 00:00:00", and we save 1449180000000.
Now we can simply group by "date".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try projecting the fields first by using the **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** in the projection operation and then group by the new fields in the group operation:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project()       
        .andExpression("year(timeCreated)").as("year")
        .andExpression("month(timeCreated)").as("month")
        .andExpression("dayOfMonth(timeCreated)").as("day"),
    group(fields().and("year").and("month").and("day"))     
        .sum("blabla").as("blabla")
);

AggregationResults<BlaBlaModel> result = 
    mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, collectionName, BlaBlaModel.class);
List<BlaBlaModel> resultList = result.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: Thanks, I could do that, but it seems much easier to use the dateToString, except I don't know why it throws an exception...

Comment: @Ayelet I'm afraid Spring Data MongoDB currently doesn't support this, there's an open JIRA ticket for that specifically [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1299)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the DateOperators.DateToString class

```
aggregationOperations.add(
      Aggregation.project("blabla", ...).
      and(DateOperators.DateToString.dateOf("timeCreated").toString("%Y-%m-%d"));
```