# How to write Mongodb aggregation group pipeline on part of Date/Time(Year, month, day, hour) in Spring?

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongo

I need help in writing mongodb aggregation pipeline in spring.

Here is a sample of my data on which I want to execute the query (Please note that the following data is a result of **Match** aggregation pipeline in spring which has conditions for the eventDate to match the range and eventName equals to 'A'):

```
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("1234567890"),
        "eventDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T03:56:04.297Z"),
        "eventName": "A"
    }

    {
        "_id": ObjectId("1234567890"),
        "eventDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T03:57:04.887Z"),
        "eventName": "A"
    }

    {
        "_id": ObjectId("1234567890"),
        "eventDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T04:05:00.497Z"),
        "eventName": "A"
    }
```

Now I want to write the **Group** aggregation pipeline on eventDate field where it should **group** on **Year**,**Month**, **Day** and **Hour** because what I'm looking for is hourly data.

Sample of the result I want it to look like which projects only eventDate and eventName fields:

```
    {
        "eventDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T03:00:00.000Z"),
        "eventName": "A"
    }

    {
        "eventDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T04:00:00.000Z"),
        "eventName": "A"
    }
```

So if you notice above that the data is in a group of hours and apart from that Minutes and seconds are now set to 0.

I tried this solution but didn't work for me:
[MongoTemplate aggregate - group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577877/mongotemplate-aggregate-group-by-date)

Any kind of help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use date arithmetic here to get the date time with minute, second and milliseconds part reset to 0.

You may need to make some adjustment based on your spring mongo version and java version.

Version : Mongo 3.2, Spring Mongo 1.9.5 Release and Java 8

Mongo Shell Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $subtract: ["$eventDate", {
                    $add: [{
                        $multiply: [{
                            $minute: "$eventDate"
                        }, 60000]
                    }, {
                        $multiply: [{
                            $second: "$eventDate"
                        }, 1000]
                    }, {
                        $millisecond: "$eventDate"
                    }]
                }]
            },
            eventName: {
                $addToSet: "$eventName"
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

Spring Code:

```
AggregationOperation group = context -> context.getMappedObject(new BasicDBObject(
    "$group", new BasicDBObject(
    "_id",
    new BasicDBObject(
        "$subtract",
        new Object[]{
            "$eventDate",
            new BasicDBObject("$add",
                new Object[]{
                    new BasicDBObject("$multiply", 
                        new Object[]{new BasicDBObject("$minute", "$eventDate"), 60000}),
                    new BasicDBObject("$multiply", 
                        new Object[]{new BasicDBObject("$second", "$eventDate"), 1000}),
                    new BasicDBObject("$millisecond", "$eventDate")
                }
            )
        }
    )
).append("eventName", new BasicDBObject("$addToSet", "$eventName"))));
```

Update: Using $project

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{
        $project: {
            eventDate: {
                $subtract: ["$eventDate", {
                    $add: [{
                        $multiply: [{
                            $minute: "$eventDate"
                        }, 60000]
                    }, {
                        $multiply: [{
                            $second: "$eventDate"
                        }, 1000]
                    }, {
                        $millisecond: "$eventDate"
                    }]
                }]
            },
            eventName: 1
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$eventDate",
            eventName: {
                $addToSet: "$eventName"
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

Spring Code

```
AggregationOperation project = context -> context.getMappedObject(new BasicDBObject(
"$project", new BasicDBObject(
"eventDate",
new BasicDBObject(
    "$subtract",
    new Object[]{
        "$eventDate",
        new BasicDBObject("$add",
            new Object[]{
                new BasicDBObject("$multiply", 
                    new Object[]{new BasicDBObject("$minute", "$eventDate"), 60000}),
                new BasicDBObject("$multiply", 
                    new Object[]{new BasicDBObject("$second", "$eventDate"), 1000}),
                new BasicDBObject("$millisecond", "$eventDate")
            }
        )
    }
)
).append("eventName", 1)));

AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("eventDate").addToSet("eventName").as("eventName");

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, group);
```

Comment: If you are not aware but $subtract is not a valid group operator, so your solution won't work!

For ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/

Comment: Did you try to run the code ? It works on 3.2 version. I'll find try to find the documentation. I'll also update solution to move the logic to `$project`.

Comment: Yes I tried running the code but it is giving me an error that invalid group operator $subtract. And sure, let me know!

Comment: What is your mongo version ? I have updated the mongo shell solution to use $project and spring solution to follow.

Comment: My project is using Mongo version 3.3.0

Comment: Updated code to use $project. It should work with most of the spring mongo version.

Comment: Yes $subtract inside project is working and I am getting the result the way I want. Thank you so much for your help.